# why does OpenCV imread() sometimes rotate the image data?

Tags: python, image, opencv

I am currectly using opencv to obtain image size of different image, but i have encounter some problem. Sometimes the width data mixed up with the height data for some reason. Here is a example:

1st example
Image size: 2988 * 5312
height: 5312
width: 2988

OpenCV data:
(2988,5312,3)

2nd example
Image size: 4160 * 3120
height: 3120
width: 4160

OpenCV data:
(3120,4160,3)

As you can see from this two example, their width and height are in different slot in the tuple. But from what i search online, img.shape[0] should represent height, img.shape[1] should represent width. But in example 1, the width and height seems mixed up. How can i fix this problem? Anyone can explain whats happening here and anyways to make it show in same way for all photo.

Comment: Are two images in the same file format? It is known for some image file formats to represent height and width in the opposite order to (height, width).

Comment: Both image are in jpg format, i guess should be in same format?

Comment: In that case, yes. Have you tried displaying the loaded images using cv2.imshow()? Are both images displayed the same way?

Comment: Just tried, seems the same for me......

Comment: could You show us the code and the images?

Comment: after wondering why the width and height are "mixed up", *look* at the data, with imshow().

Comment: Probably EXIF and probably only for JPEG images? EXIF allows digital cameras to save time by skipping rotation/mirroring operations. It just saves the image as is with flags that guide the image reader on how to interpret the image offline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine **OpenCV** is looking at the *"EXIF Orientation"* field. You can disable that with:

```
im = cv2.imread(filename, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR|cv2.IMREAD_IGNORE_ORIENTATION)
```

---

You can check the orientation easily in your Terminal with `exiftool`:

```
exiftool YOURIMAGE
```